# Selenium WebDriver cannot click element even though it seems to be visible

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Python 2, Selenium using **Firefox**, on this [page](https://etf.invesco.com/ie/private/en/products), I am trying have the driver click the following button (the magnifying glass):

[image]

```
<button id="search-btn" type="button" class="header__user-menu-item header__search-btn">
          <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
          <img src="/sites/default/themes/custom/smp_bootstrap/images/search.svg" class="header__user-menu-icon fa fa-search fa-fw" alt="Search">
        </button>
```

I use the following code for the XPath of the element, `x = '//*[@id="search-btn"]'`:

```
x = '//*[@id="search-btn"]'

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, x)))
except:
    print "Element not clickable"
else:
    found_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(x)
    try:
        found_element.click()
    except:
        raise
```

Selenium's common exception `EC.element_to_be_clickable` doesn't identify the element, nor does `visibility_of_element_located` nor `presence_of_element_located`.

Strangely however, at a few occasions the driver has actually been able to identify the element and then perform `driver.find_element_by_xpath(x)` which appears to find the XPath and `.click()` the element. At that point everything works. For a second I thought that the script was to quick to execute the operation before the page had loaded, but 5 seconds `WebDriverWait` is plenty to load the page, and I have an additional page-load-in sleep before that.

The element doesn't seem to be in an IFrame. I have already passed through the "Accept Conditions"-buttons, etc.

I am running the latest versions of Firefox (61.0), Selenium (3.13) and Geckodriver (0.21.0).

What could be the problem here?

Comment: which driver do you used ?

Comment: @cle-b Firefox. Sorry, will add that to the question.

Comment: try to use Chrome, in chrome works xpath and id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Firefox as the driver, I was able to click the element by executing JavaScript:

```
driver.execute_script("window.document.getElementById('search-btn').click()")
```

---

Note that the above is a non-conventional measure, which shouldn't be needed. The other answers are correct and the usual way to do it.

The problem resides with the Selenium driver being unable to identify XPath elements, due to a bug in the current version of geckodriver (0.21.0) combined with Selenium (3.13.0), see: [Broken pipe error selenium webdriver, when there is a gap between commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239512/broken-pipe-error-selenium-webdriver-when-there-is-a-gap-between-commands/51240227)

I downgraded to geckodriver 0.20.1 to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 1):

if i get element with `By.ID` not with `By.XPATH` this works, maybe you give wrong `xpath` ?

if a use `xpath` this also work `x = '//*[@id="search-btn"]'`

```
id = 'search-btn'
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, id)))
element.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of targeting the `<button>` element for a more granular approach you can target the `<img>` tag as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@class='header__user-menu-icon fa fa-search fa-fw' and @alt='Search']"))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I did however try that earlier, and it has no bearing on the issue unfortunately.