# Broken pipe error selenium webdriver, when there is a gap between commands?

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver

`Ubuntu 18.x + selenium webdriver(Firefox)`

Facing a weird problem, the following block works if I `run` all of it together

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://indiamart.com'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

This is happening with every `url` I have tried.

However if I execute one line at a time, it gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/media/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 326, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/media/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/media/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 472, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/media/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 495, in _request
    self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 986, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

This is the `error` on the `code`

`driver.get(url)`

However if I execute the same line again after the `Broken Pipe error` it works and gets the `url`.

I am very very confused. Can someone help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Where is `url` defined?

Comment: Hi Andrei, left it vague because it happens with every url.

Comment: Please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692284/brokenpipeerror-in-python

Comment: can you run it in non-headless mode, so you can see the browser window opening and (perhaps) closing?

Comment: Try with chrome and see if same issue happens

Comment: @λuser it is showing me the window. The window is still open when going line by line.

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov seems like a very good explanation, trying to wrap my brain around it but I am very new to python and coding in general.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Will try, but would be nice to find a way around it on firefox.

Comment: @Sid Good luck ))

Comment: I have seen and experienced this recently, but its a hard one to debug and find which component in the whole chain causes it

Answer (score 5):

This is a known bug of the latest build v0.21.0 of geckodriver matched with the latest version of selenium v3.11

To work around this bug either:
a) [downgrade geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) to v0.20.1 or earlier 
b) wait for the bugfix/mitigations be rolled out in the upcoming versions of selenium and/or geckodriver

This bug originates from newly added support in v 0.21 of Keep-Alive feature. However, the default timeout from geckodriver in 0.21 is set to 5s, which is exceptionally short.

This bug is tracked [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1304) for geckodriver and [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/6103) for selenium.

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

...implies that the *GeckoDriver* server process has received a `SIGPIPE` while writing to a socket. `BrokenPipeError` usually happens when a process tries to write to a socket which is fully closed on the client side. This may be happening when the *GeckoDriver* server process doesn't wait till all the data from the server is received and simply tries to close the socket (using close function)it had opened with the client.

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [**How to prevent errno 32 broken pipe?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866792/how-to-prevent-errno-32-broken-pipe)

### Solution

- Moving forward as you are invoking `click()` on your desired element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* as follows:

  ```
  driver.get(url)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "xpath"))).click()
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

- Again, the `BrokenPipeError` can also occur if your *request* is **blocked** or takes too long and after *request-side* (server) timeout. The server may close the connection and then, when the *response-side* (client) tries to write to the socket, it may throw a `BrokenPipeError`. Inthis cases you can set `page_load_timeout` as follows:

  ```
  driver.set_page_load_timeout(3)
  ```

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [**How to set the timeout of 'driver.get' for python selenium 3.8.0?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694922/how-to-set-the-timeout-of-driver-get-for-python-selenium-3-8-0/47695227#47695227)

Answer (score 1):

In the recent release, they have the issue, upgrade the selenium with latest release

**pip install -U selenium**