# Window keeps closing after running selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Everytime I run this code the window opens blank and then loads the required page for about 1 second before closing.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/*****/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

An error has come up once or twice saying `[268:10204:0208/163438.782:ERROR:broker_win.cc(55)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)` but it only appears sometimes even though the code hasn't changed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mind uninstall and reinstall selenium package. Also use latest chrome driver version if not using alraedy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239512/broken-pipe-error-selenium-webdriver-when-there-is-a-gap-between-commands may help you

Comment: I have tried reinstalling and still doesn't work. What I have noticed is when running the file with command line it works fine. When I run it on visual studio code it will do all the steps I have added, like signing into a page and clicking on buttons etc, but then will close immediately after there is nothing else to do.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
ERROR:broker_win.cc(55)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)
```

...implies that the pipe is broken as if the browser side has been closed.

This error is defined in [broker_win.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/62.0.3178.1/mojo/edk/system/broker_win.cc#49) within the Chromium code repository as follows:

```
Channel::MessagePtr WaitForBrokerMessage(PlatformHandle platform_handle,
                     BrokerMessageType expected_type) {
  char buffer[kMaxBrokerMessageSize];
  DWORD bytes_read = 0;
  BOOL result = ::ReadFile(platform_handle.handle, buffer,
               kMaxBrokerMessageSize, &bytes_read, nullptr);
  if (!result) {
    // The pipe may be broken if the browser side has been closed, e.g. during
    // browser shutdown. In that case the ReadFile call will fail and we
    // shouldn't continue waiting.
    PLOG(ERROR) << "Error reading broker pipe";
    return nullptr;
  }
```

The main reason you see this error is because the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) controlled *Chrome* browser gets detected and the navigation gets blocked.

---

### Solution

As a solution you may need to configure the *ChromeDriver* / *Chrome* with certain configurations so [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven *Chrome Browsing Context* doesn't get detected.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)
- [Is there a way to use Selenium WebDriver without informing the document that it is controlled by WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862023/is-there-a-way-to-use-selenium-webdriver-without-informing-the-document-that-it/52900495#52900495)

---

### tl; dr

[Broken pipe error selenium webdriver, when there is a gap between commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239512/broken-pipe-error-selenium-webdriver-when-there-is-a-gap-between-commands/51240227#51240227)

Answer (score 0):

I am using ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.138 placed in C:\Windows and this is whats working for me

```
from selenium import webdriver

class Stackoverflow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
        self.options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        self.options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options)
        self.driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
          "source": """
            Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
              get: () => undefined
            })
          """
        })
        self.driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.enable", {})
        self.driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders", {"headers": {"User-Agent": "browser"}})
        self.driver.get("https://www.stackoverflow.com/")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Stackoverflow()
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best possible workarounds is to set `Sleep()`, so that the browser doesn't close:

```
import time 

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
time.sleep(3000)  #this makes browser not to close.
```

Additional reading
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Anyhow after 3000 sec it will close

Comment: This will basically keep the browser open for 3000sec, later after 3000sec it will again close immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to keep open your browser window then you can do the following which I mentioned in this post:
[Chrome browser closes immediately after loading from selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74651555/20327380)

#if you find this effective then do mark it as useful

Thank You

Subhankar Chakraborty