# Keep getting "that page doesn't exist" error when scraping twitter with selenium and webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, twitter, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://twitter.com/WholesomeMeme")
html = driver.page_source
driver.close()
open("twitter.html", "w", encoding='utf8').write(html)
```

A Google chrome instance was successfully opened by executing the code above and I was able to see the wholesomeMeme profile page, but when I open `twitter.html`, only "Sorry, that page doesn't exist" shows up.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have used your code with a couple of additional options and was able to retrive the *Page Source* partially before writing the partial *Page Source* to `twitter.html` as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://twitter.com/WholesomeMeme')
  html = driver.page_source
  print(driver.page_source)
  driver.quit()
  open("twitter.html", "w", encoding='utf8').write(html)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <html dir="ltr" lang="en" style="font-size: 15px;"><head><meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0,viewport-fit=cover">
  .
  <html dir="ltr" lang="en" style="font-size: 15px;"><head><meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0,viewport-fit=cover">
  .
  .
  .
    <noscript>
      <form action="https://mobile.twitter.com/i/nojs_router?path=%2FWholesomeMeme" method="POST" style="background-color: #fff; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 9999;">
        <div style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif; line-height: 24px; margin: 10%; width: 80%;">
      <p>We've detected that JavaScript is disabled in your browser. Would you like to proceed to legacy Twitter?</p>
      <p style="margin: 20px 0;">
        <button type="submit" style="background-color: #1da1f2; border-radius: 100px; border: none; box-shadow: none; color: #fff; cursor: pointer; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px; padding: 6px 16px;">Yes</button>
      </p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </noscript>
    .
    <div id="react-root" style="height:100%;display:flex;"><div class="css-1dbjc4n r-13awgt0 r-12vffkv">
    .
  //# sourceMappingURL=runtime.19384dc4.js.map
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" nonce="" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/web/polyfills.604422d4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" nonce="" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/web/vendors~main.31775294.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" nonce="" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/web/i18n-rweb/en.cb24d894.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" nonce="" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/web/i18n-horizon/en.d212af84.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" nonce="" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/web/main.a4500454.js"></script>
  <script nonce="">
    if (!window.__SCRIPTS_LOADED__['main']) {
      document.getElementById('ScriptLoadFailure').style.display = 'block';
    }
  </script>
  <script async="" src="https://twitter.com/i/js_inst?c_name=ui_metrics"></script></body></html>
  [11684:11992:0605/150054.450:ERROR:broker_win.cc(55)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)
  ```
- Observation: The following error is observed:

  ```
  Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)
  ```

---

### Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)

This error message...

```
ERROR:broker_win.cc(55)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)
```

...implies that the pipe is broken as if the browser side has been closed.

This error is defined in [broker_win.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/62.0.3178.1/mojo/edk/system/broker_win.cc#49) within the Chromium code repository as follows:

```
Channel::MessagePtr WaitForBrokerMessage(PlatformHandle platform_handle,
                     BrokerMessageType expected_type) {
  char buffer[kMaxBrokerMessageSize];
  DWORD bytes_read = 0;
  BOOL result = ::ReadFile(platform_handle.handle, buffer,
               kMaxBrokerMessageSize, &bytes_read, nullptr);
  if (!result) {
    // The pipe may be broken if the browser side has been closed, e.g. during
    // browser shutdown. In that case the ReadFile call will fail and we
    // shouldn't continue waiting.
    PLOG(ERROR) << "Error reading broker pipe";
    return nullptr;
  }
```

---

### Reason

The main reason you see this error is because the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) controlled *Chrome* browser gets detected and the navigation gets blocked.

---

### Solution

As a solution you may need to configure the *ChromeDriver* / *Chrome* with certain configurations so [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven *Chrome Browsing Context* doesn't get detected.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)
- [Is there a way to use Selenium WebDriver without informing the document that it is controlled by WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862023/is-there-a-way-to-use-selenium-webdriver-without-informing-the-document-that-it/52900495#52900495)

---

### tl; dr

[Broken pipe error selenium webdriver, when there is a gap between commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239512/broken-pipe-error-selenium-webdriver-when-there-is-a-gap-between-commands/51240227#51240227)